# Стратегия написания кода COM сервера

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, com, generics

Хочу написать расширение для CAD приложения. В одном из этапов столкнулся с такой вот задачей:

1. Получить управление COM объектом для CAD в `Runtime object table`.
2. Контролировать выбранный COM процесс (в случае открытия нового экземпляра подобного приложения), а также его потерю (в случае закрытия приложения)
3. Вызвать нужный процесс (например, для печати в PDF, или экспорта в Excel) и получить управление.

---

1. Какой лучше путь избрать?

   1. Получить управление над приложением через `Marshal.GetActiveObject()` - но, всегда ли это работает?
   2. Получить управление над приложением через моникеры и контекств в ROT.
2. Контролировать и "удерживать" выбранный COM либо через его ID, либо через какой либо иной идентификатор. Изменение состояний в ROT можно выполнить через "наблюдателя", например, `Reactive Extension`.
3. Вызывать процесс можно пробовать через "дефолтные пути" установки приложений, но это нехорошо, нужно вызывать зарегистрированный GUID (для "стандартных" приложений он всю жизнь (наверное?) не меняется), далее "удержание" процесса как в разделе 1.

Допустим, сегодня у меня имеются приложения Word, Excel, SolidWorks. Завтра может появится AutoCAD, PDF и пр. Соответственно, лучше создать фабрику классов. Также запутался.

Создал генерик "обертки" для COM классов:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace COMServer         
{
    public interface ICOMType<T>
    {
        T Item
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        int ProcessID
        {
            get;
        }

        string Build
        {
            get;
        }

        string Version
        {
            get;
        }

        int Name
        {
            get;
        } 
        string GetNameOpenProject();
    }
}
```

Где Т - это интерфейс COM класса

С фабрикой дженериком ну просто ступор :(

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace COMServer
{
    public abstract class COMTypeFactory<TResult>
    {
        public COMTypeFactory()
        {
            // какой нибудь конструктор
        }

        public override TResult CallExistInstance()
        {
            // Проблема
        }
    }
}
```

Помогите написать генерик фабрику обертку и пример инициализации класса (например Excel)

Заранее благодарю за конструктивный и полезный диалог  :)